# From relativistic equation to find Dirac matrices

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

Is this possible and then how?
$$((\gamma \otimes \mathbf\sigma)\bullet\mathbf p)(\gamma^\prime\otimes\mathbf 1_2) = \gamma\gamma^\prime\otimes\sigma \bullet \mathbf p $$
where $\gamma$ and $\gamma^\prime$ are using to factorize later we see $\gamma^0=\gamma^\prime\otimes1_2$,$\gamma^1=\gamma\otimes\sigma_1$,$\gamma^2=\gamma\otimes\sigma_2$ $\gamma^3=\gamma\otimes\sigma_3$  where $\gamma^1,\gamma^2,\gamma3$ are Dirac Matrices, $ \mathbf\sigma $ is Pauli Spin Matrix, p is momentum four vector $p=(E/c,-p_1,-p_2,-p_3)$ and $1_2$ is 2x2 unit matrix i.e$$1_2 = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right)$$ $$\sigma_1 = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1  \\ 1 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$$ $$\sigma_2 = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & -i  \\ i & 0\end{matrix}\right)$$$$\sigma_3 = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0  \\ 0 & -1\end{matrix}\right)$$
I know about matrix mixed product( ($A\otimes B)(C \otimes D)=AC\otimes BD$ ) but I can't understand how this possible I shall be happy to get any answer.
Here I put this Image from Where I have got this query.
Thanks.[image: Here I put this Image Where I have got this query]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be an answer.I am not quite sure about that.
$$(\gamma^\prime\otimes 1_2)\{(\gamma\otimes\pmb\sigma)\}\bullet \pmb p\} =\{(\gamma^\prime\otimes 1_2)(\gamma\otimes\pmb\sigma)\}\bullet \pmb p$$
[Here I assume $(\gamma^\prime\otimes 1_2)$ just like scaler]
$$=\{\gamma^\prime\gamma\otimes1_2\pmb\sigma\}\bullet \pmb p$$
[By using mixed product theorem $(A\otimes B).(C\otimes D)=AC\otimes BD$]$$=(\gamma^\prime\gamma\otimes\pmb \sigma)\bullet p$$
Similarly
$$\{(\gamma\otimes\pmb \sigma)\bullet p\}.\{\gamma^\prime\otimes 1_2\}=\{(\gamma\otimes\pmb \sigma).(\gamma^\prime\otimes 1_2)\}\bullet \pmb p=(\gamma\gamma^\prime\otimes\pmb\sigma 1_2)\bullet p= (\gamma\gamma^\prime\otimes\pmb\sigma)\bullet p$$
Note:I am not sure that there exist any such type  rule to exchange inner product with direct product.

[image]

Comment: Hi baponkar, please don't paste screenshots of math. We have MathJax built into the site for this reason (and you even used it in your question!).

Comment: Well I'm glad you found what you were looking. You might want to see if you can start with Klein-Gordon relativistic wave equation and generate the Dirac equation - which is how Dirac found the $\gamma$ matrices - or the Dirac Clifford algebra

Comment: @CinaedSimson I'm currently trying to reconstruct his original reasoning, but It's still unclear how he deduced the chiral representation of the $\gamma$s (or any other equivalent representation, for that matter). All I have obtained so far - starting from "factoring" the Klein-Gordon equation - is the anti-commutation relation $\{\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu\}=2g^{\mu\nu}\mathbb{I}_4$. It's hard to believe that he just guessed correctly, by "extending" 
the Pauli matrices. There are quite a few ways of doing that